# How to integrate magnolia blossom module with spring mvc

Tags: maven, jsp, spring-mvc, content-management-system, magnolia

I have created web application in spring.So finally I got requirement to integrate a CMS to my project.I decided to use magnolia with blossom.I am new to magnolia and cms terminology.How should I integrate CMS to spring application.I referred documentation and some examples but I haven't got any clarity on it.So finally what's my doubt is how to integrate magnolia blossom with my spring application with out doing tight coupling.

These are the links I referred [Refr Link](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Blossom+module).

[Sample magnolia project Ref Link](https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/BLOSSOM/repos/samples/browse) In this example they have given multi module maven project , in that one module for blossom and one for webapp magnolia.So here I haven't understood how to call my spring application to render my jsp pages or my app associated blog pages.

So please share your ideas or suggestion to implement a cms to spring....

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you link is pretty clear on it 
- to get things working you need to deploy Magnolia and your spring app in same war file.
- your spring controller becomes Magnolia page or component template. In case you need dialogs you create those in your code too by annotating appropriate code as a dialog.
- editing/placing of something at give URI/page location is then done via Magnolia using template (controller) found via annotation in your spring code.

If you have concrete issue, it would help to describe it and explain what you tried and what didn't work and where you are actually stuck.

Otherwise you perhaps want to try first few examples of working with just the CMS part of Magnolia and only once you understand that, start merging the two.

Comment: tq for the reply.My requirement is not to merge two things in single war because we already developed entire spring project and setuped  continuous integration workflow with jenkins so I don't want to disturb the existing code and environment .So What I am thinking is I will run magnolia in one server and my app in another server so in that case how can I render my jsp pages and its associated assets(img,css,js) to my application using some rest calls or any other solution??.If my thinking is wrong correct me...

Comment: @Jan.If my thing is correct means can I get response including external css ,javascript and images from the rest call/service.

Comment: yes, you can get everything over the rest, but then you don't need blossom module at all. Blossom purpose is so that you can make your spring controllers being templates directly and use annotations and code to create definitions and dialogs instead of pure yaml or jcr based configuration.